# poner imagenes a un tamaño determinado en laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap

Al momento de subir imagenes,ay algunas  de diferentes tamaños.

Y queda de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="container"> <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
      <div class="form-group" style="vertical-align: all;">
              <label class="d-block" for="file_hoja_solicitud">
                  <b>Imagen 1</b>
              </label>

              @if($failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud)
         <div class="embed-container"> 
               <embed style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left;" src="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud])}}"></embed>
         </div>
                  <a href="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud])}}" class="mt-1 d-inline-block">DESCARGAR</a>

            <div class="form-check ml-3 mt-1 d-inline-block">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id="failure_close_check_f1" name="failure_close_check_f1" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                Desea cambiar el archivo?
              </label>
            </div>
            @endif
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_hoja_solicitud" name="file_hoja_solicitud" placeholder="Ingrese número de serie" 
            {{($failuresDetail->name_random_file_solicitud)?"style=display:none disabled":""}}>
          </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="d-block" for="file_hoja_garantia"><b>Imagen 2</b></label>
            @if($failuresDetail->name_random_file_garantia)
             <div class="embed-container">    

               <embed   style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left;" src="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_garantia])}}"></embed>
         </div>
            <a href="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_garantia])}}" class="mt-1 d-inline-block">DESCARGAR</a>
            <div class="form-check ml-3 mt-1 d-inline-block">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id="failure_close_check_f2" name="failure_close_check_f2" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                Desea cambiar el archivo?
              </label>
            </div>
            @endif
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_hoja_garantia" name="file_hoja_garantia" placeholder="Ingrese número de serie" 
            {{($failuresDetail->name_random_file_garantia)?"style=display:none disabled":""}}>
          </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
             <div class="form-group">
            <label class="d-block" for="file_hoja_sustitucion"><B>Imagen 3</b></label>
            @if($failuresDetail->name_random_file_sustitucion)
             <div class="embed-container">    

               <embed   style="width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left;" src="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_sustitucion])}}"></embed>
         </div>
            <a target="_blank" href="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$failuresDetail->name_random_file_sustitucion])}}" class="mt-1 d-inline-block">DESCARGAR</a>
            <div class="form-check ml-3 mt-1 d-inline-block">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input id="failure_close_check_f3" name="failure_close_check_f3" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                Desea cambiar el archivo?
              </label>
            </div>
            @endif
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file_hoja_sustitucion" name="file_hoja_sustitucion" placeholder="Ingrese número de serie" 
            {{($failuresDetail->name_random_file_sustitucion)?"style=display:none disabled":""}}>
          </div>
</div>
```

el css

```
.embed-container:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.embed-container>embed {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  float: left;
}
```

Lo que busco es que se vea de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que lo mejor es que utilices un paquete que te apoye a la manipulación de imágenes te recomiendo cualquiera de estas dos:

- https://github.com/spatie/image
- http://image.intervention.io/

en lo personal Spatie siempre se caracteriza por tener buenos paquetes y buena documentación, te dejo su doc: https://docs.spatie.be/image/v1/introduction

Un Ejemplo de como podrias renderizar la imagen.

```
Image::load($pathToImage)
   ->width(100)
   ->height(100)
   ->save($pathToNewImage);
```